# Escape special characters in header

Tags: php

In a webpage a user can enter strings into input elements. After the form is submitted, all inputs are verified against rules. After the validation the inpit page is displayed again to the user with marked errors and the already filled in input elements.

Partial code in the validation page for sending back the data:

```
$query_string = '?filename='.$timed_file_name . '&name=' . $name . '&text='.$text; 
header('Location: http://' . $server_dir . $next_page . $query_string);
```

It's obvious that the ampersand cannot be used in the header, because if I type jack&jones it will mess up the header and php will return only jack.

I can do it in an ugly way:

Validation page:

```
$name = html_entity_decode($name); 
$name = str_replace("&","aammppeerrssaanndd",$name);
```

Input page:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
if (strpos($name,'aappoossttrroopphh') !== false) {
    $name = html_entity_decode($name); 
    $name = str_replace("aappoossttrroopphh","&",$name);
}
```

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to [URL encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your values.  `& == %26`, not `& == "aammppeerrssaanndd"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the URL, run your variables through this:

```
$var = urlencode( $var );
```

And when showing users the results, go the other way:

```
$var = urldecode( $var );
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. One problem is that from jenny's it creates jenny\\\'s

Comment: It sounds like you have `magic_quotes` enabled on your server. On the output to users, try something like `$var = stripslashes( urldecode( $var ) );`

Comment: One other thing to note is that, depending on the type of input with which the user is interacting, `urldecode()` may not be necessary in your display to users. Web browsers will render what most humans expect to see when HTML entities are presented in most input elements.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I figured out that `urldecode()` was not necessary, because it messed up ', " and +. However I had to use 'stripslashes()' and 'htmlspecialchars()' on the input page to get the appropriate result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

In your case, it would used like this:

```
$query_string = '?filename='. urlencode($timed_file_name) . '&name=' . urlencode($name) . '&text='. urlencode($text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use [http-build-query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) this makes the query string for you from an array.

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) say:

> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

Example

```
$a = array("be"=>"a","wonderful"=>"happier & great","but"=>"strange like @%");
echo http_build_query($a);
//gives "be=a&wonderful= happier +%26+great&but=strange+like+%40%25"
```

So in your case you would use:

```
$args = array('filename'=>$timed_file_name, 'name'=>$name, 'text'=>$text);
$query_string = "?".http_build_query($args);
```